# What do these labels mean in the context of VGA timings?

Tags: fpga, vga

This is the image provided with the De1 SoC development board. I do not know what some of the abbreviations mean in this context

[image]

VGA_R   [7..0]   values for red pixels
VGA_G   [7..0]   values for green pixels
VGA_B   [7..0]   values for blue pixels
VGA_CLK    this I believe is the pixel clock, my screen is 1280x1024 pixels so  108MHz
VGA_SYNC_N Do not know what this is
VGA_BLANK_N Do not know what this is

I have done all my timings for HSYNC and VSYNC, but am unsure what signals should go into VGA_SYNC_N and VGA_BLANK_N.

thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question – VGA defines HSync and VSync signals, and your job is to create VGA, so these signal are probably exactly these. Other than that, read the datasheet of your DAC.

Comment: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADV7123.pdf

Comment: CLK = #of pix * frame rate,  SYNC_N= H_sync (neg edge)  , BLANK = V_sync ( blanking interval) = frame rate, non-interlaced